# Plot line and bar chart from pandas dataframe with time index and different periodicities on shared x-axis

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, grid, time-series, bar-chart

I have a pandas data frame which looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=30)
A = np.repeat(0.7, 30)
B = np.append(np.append(np.repeat(np.NaN, 9), [1]), np.append(np.append(np.repeat(np.NaN, 9), [2]), np.append(np.repeat(np.NaN, 9), [3])))
C = np.append(np.append(np.repeat(np.NaN, 14), [0.5]), np.repeat(np.NaN, 15))
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=A, B=B, C=C), index=index)

In[1]: df

Out[1]: 
              A   B    C
2000-01-01  0.7 NaN  NaN
2000-01-02  0.7 NaN  NaN
2000-01-03  0.7 NaN  NaN
2000-01-04  0.7 NaN  NaN
2000-01-05  0.7 NaN  NaN
2000-01-06  0.7 NaN  NaN
2000-01-07  0.7 NaN  NaN
2000-01-08  0.7 NaN  NaN
2000-01-09  0.7 NaN  NaN
2000-01-10  0.7   1  NaN
2000-01-11  0.7 NaN  NaN
2000-01-12  0.7 NaN  NaN
2000-01-13  0.7 NaN  NaN
2000-01-14  0.7 NaN  NaN
2000-01-15  0.7 NaN  0.5
2000-01-16  0.7 NaN  NaN
2000-01-17  0.7 NaN  NaN
2000-01-18  0.7 NaN  NaN
2000-01-19  0.7 NaN  NaN
2000-01-20  0.7   2  NaN
2000-01-21  0.7 NaN  NaN
2000-01-22  0.7 NaN  NaN
2000-01-23  0.7 NaN  NaN
2000-01-24  0.7 NaN  NaN
2000-01-25  0.7 NaN  NaN
2000-01-26  0.7 NaN  NaN
2000-01-27  0.7 NaN  NaN
2000-01-28  0.7 NaN  NaN
2000-01-29  0.7 NaN  NaN
2000-01-30  0.7   3  NaN
```

What I want to achieve is to plot the columns "A" and "B" as lines in one plot and the column "B" as bar plot with values annotated (i.e. "0.5") in a subplot below the first one. Everythin has to be aligned to the index of the dataframe. (In R I´d use gridExtra to arrange everything.) Is there a clever pythonic way to qickly arrange everything and have a nice grid in the background of the plot?

The following code seems to fit well to start with

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(12, 4))
df[["A", "B"]].plot(ax=axes[0])
df["B"].plot(kind="bar", ax=axes[1]);
```

I get the following plot:

[image]

Which is not excatly what I am looking for. The things that I am seeking to adjust are written in text form.

Answer (score 0):

start with this:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(12, 4))
df[["A","B"]].plot(ax=axes[0])
df["B"].plot(kind="bar", ax=axes[1]);
```

And adjust the spacing and labeling as neccesary

Comment: Thanks @putonspectacles for your post. I would be very happy if you could add some more details such as the plot I posted above from your example (thanks again!) looks a bit more to what I am looking for?